# Is the Spark-Cassandra-connector node aware?

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Is Datastax Cassandra community edition integration with Spark community edition using spark-cassandra-connector community edition node aware or is this feature reserved for Enterprise editions only?

By node awareness I mean if Spark will send job execution to the nodes owning the data

Comment: There is no "DataStax Cassandra Community Edition". Did you mean open-source Cassandra? Also, the spark-cassandra-connector is open-source so no "community edition" either. Can you please clarify? Cheers! 

Comment: I had an impression that Datastax has its own build of community edition of Cassandra.
Thanx for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Spark connector is node-aware and will function in that manner with both DSE and (open source) Apache Cassandra.

In fact on a `SELECT` it knows how to hash the partition keys to a token, and send queries on specific token ranges only to the nodes responsible for that data.  It can do this, because (like the Cassandra Java driver) it has a window into node-to-node gossip and can see things like node status (up/down) and token range assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark it is referred to as [**data locality**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-locality).

Data locality can only be achieved if both the JVMs for Cassandra and the Spark worker/executor are co-located within the same OSI. By definition, data can only be local if the executors doing the processing are running on the same server (OSI) as the Cassandra node.

During the [initial contact](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connection-management) with the cluster, the driver retrieves information about the cluster topology -- available nodes, rack/DC configuration, token ownership. Since the driver is aware of where nodes are located, it will always try to connect to the "closest" node in the same (local) data centre.

If the Spark workers/executors are co-located with the Cassandra node, the Spark-Cassandra-connector will process Spark partitions on the nodes that own the data where possible to reduce the amount of data shuffling across the network.

There are [methods such as `joinWithCassandraTable()`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable) which maximise data locality where possible. Additionally, [the `repartitionByCassandraReplica()` method](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#example-join-with-generic-rdd) splits the Spark partitions so they are mapped to Cassandra replicas that own the data.

This functionality works for both open-source Cassandra clusters and [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) clusters. Cheers!